# Удаление выделенных checkbox'ов в checkedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно удалить выделенные чекбоксы в `checkedListBox` по нажатию кнопки. Вот мой код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems);
}
```

Но почему-то он не удаляет их. НО если заменить `CheckedItems` на `SelectedItem`, то он удаляет.

Comment: В чём заключается вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CheckedItems` - те на которых галочка,
`SelectedItems` - итемы, которые ты выбираешь.

Если тебе нужно удалить чекбоксы, на которых стоят галочки, то у тебя верный код, а если хочешь удалить выделенные, то

`private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(checkedListBox1.SelectedItems);
}`

Comment: @mymedia, это ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy, нет, это больше похоже на комментарий. Всё же в ответе ожидается увидеть хотя бы небольшой примерчик кода.